# How do I verify my home encryption passphrase

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

I just reinstalled Xubuntu 16.04 on my system and chose the option to encrypt the home folder. I was presented with a terminal window to type in a passphrase. The passphrase was not displayed as I typed, and it did not give me an opportunity to re-type it for verification. I made at least one typo and had to backspace. Is there a way to determine if I typed it correctly?

Sorry if this has been asked before. It seems like an obvious question, but I can't find an answer anywhere.